# Cloud Carousel patched for iPad not responding to "click" events

Tags: ios, cloud, carousel, tap

We are using Professor Cloud's Cloud Carousel on a website, and we need to make this function on iOS devices as well.

We've patched the Carousel's javascript code using AlbanX's Cloud Carousel Touch script:

http://www.albanx.com/?pid=5&subid=18

http://www.albanx.com/programing/cloudcarouseltouch/jslibs/cloud-carousel.1.0.5.js (code download)

And the carousel is working great with one exception....we need the items in the carousel to be clickable (link to other pages) and on iOS devices (we're not testing other mobile platforms at this time) these items are no longer responding to click events.

I'm fairly new at Javascript coding, so I'm looking for assistance changing the existing script so that clicking on an item without a gesture (in other words, a tap instead of a swipe) results in the link being followed instead of the carousel rotating.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.